# Reduce background noise in AVAudioEngine

Tags: ios, swift, avaudiosession, avaudioengine

I'm using the below code to input voice from iPhone and playing on speaker simultaneously. But I'm getting a lot of noise feedback sound. How can that be fixed?

```
import AVFoundation
    // Setup engine and node instances
    var engine = AVAudioEngine()
    var delay = AVAudioUnitDelay()
    var reverb = AVAudioUnitReverb()
    var mixer = engine.mainMixerNode
    var input = engine.inputNode
    var output = engine.outputNode
    var format = input.inputFormatForBus(0)
    var error:NSError?
    // Attach FX nodes to engine
    engine.attachNode(delay)
    engine.attachNode(reverb)
    // Connect nodes
    engine.connect(input, to: delay, format: format)
    engine.connect(delay, to: reverb, format: format)
    engine.connect(reverb, to: output, format: format)
    // Start engine
    engine.startAndReturnError(&error)
```

Comment: What do you call `noise feedback` exactly? A loop feedback (Larsen)? Something else?

Comment: Yes, a loop feedback.

Comment: It means that the audio coming out of the speaker is caught by the mic, making a classic loop feedback. Unfortunately the solution is not with code - it's a matter of not setting the output level too high, so that it's not caught by the mic. Or to ask the user to use headphones.

Comment: I thought so, but one of the app on the app store has achieved this...